Error jumping from bootloader to application with STM32F412
I have an issue with jumping from the bootloader to the application.
If I make the jump before entering the infinite loop, everything works, but if I do it from inside the loop, it doesn't work.
I also tried putting a condition that makes it exit the loop and then execute the jump outside after passing through the loop, but even in this case, it doesn't work.
If I step through the bootloader code, I reach the last instruction (pmain_app()) without any problems.
I have conducted various tests, and the only way to make it work inside the loop is by not initializing any peripherals.
I don't know what else to try.
#include "main.h"
#include "dma.h"
#include "fatfs.h"
#include "spi.h"
#include "usb_host.h"
#include "gpio.h"
#include "crc.h"

extern TIM_HandleTypeDef htim11;
extern const uint32_t   app_vector;  //app_vector is defined in ld file

#define APPLICATION_START_ADDRESS       (uint32_t *)&app_vector 

void SystemClock_Config(void);
void MX_USB_HOST_Process(void);
void JumpToApplication(void);


int main(void)
{
    HAL_Init();
    SystemClock_Config();
    MX_GPIO_Init();
    __enable_irq();

    volatile static int xxx;

    //JumpToApplication() //Here works

    while(true)
    {
        retStatus_t ret = retNothing;

        if(xxx++ >= 10000) ret = retJump;

        switch(ret)
        {
            case retNothing:
            break;

            case retJump:
                __disable_irq();
                JumpToApplication(); //Here it only works if I don't initialize any peripherals.
            break;

            case retReset:
                NVIC_SystemReset();
            break;
        }
    }
    //JumpToApplication() //Here doesn't work
}

void JumpToApplication(void)
{
    __HAL_RCC_GPIOA_CLK_DISABLE();
    __HAL_RCC_GPIOB_CLK_DISABLE();
    __HAL_RCC_GPIOC_CLK_DISABLE();
    __HAL_RCC_GPIOD_CLK_DISABLE();

    HAL_TIM_Base_DeInit(&htim11);

    void (*pmain_app)(void);

    __disable_irq();

    __HAL_RCC_CRC_CLK_DISABLE();

    SCB->VTOR = (uint32_t)APPLICATION_START_ADDRESS;
    __set_MSP((uint32_t)*APPLICATION_START_ADDRESS);
    pmain_app = (void (*)(void)) * (APPLICATION_START_ADDRESS + 4);

    __DSB();
    __ISB();

    pmain_app();
}



You disable IRQ twice (once before jump function, and once inside it). Shouldn't matter, but you should know 2) Do you actually enter application reset handler? 3) Does application reset handler init all the data? Is your application position-independent? (.data section). Can you find the specific line it fails at? Does it jump to correct address?


I rearranged the function as you can see below and it works fine:
void jumpToApplication(void)
{
    void (*pmain_app)(void);

    HAL_GPIO_DeInit(GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_All);
    HAL_GPIO_DeInit(GPIOB, GPIO_PIN_All);
    HAL_GPIO_DeInit(GPIOC, GPIO_PIN_All);
    HAL_GPIO_DeInit(GPIOD, GPIO_PIN_All);

    HAL_SPI_MspDeInit(&hspi1);
    HAL_CRC_MspDeInit(&hcrc);

    HAL_TIM_Base_DeInit(&htim11);
    HAL_DeInit();                

    __disable_irq();

    __DSB();
    __ISB();

    SCB->VTOR = (uint32_t)APPLICATION_START_ADDRESS;
    __set_MSP((uint32_t)*APPLICATION_START_ADDRESS);

    pmain_app = (void (*)(void)) * (APPLICATION_START_ADDRESS + 1);
    pmain_app();
}

